# zoomin/zoomout of button on focus after specified amount of time

Tags: jquery, html

i have an application which zoomin/zoomout image inside button on focus/blur but problem is i want zoomin to be called only if focus remains on button for 2sec how do i do this.

here is my [demo](http://www.jsfiddle.net/jAxg9/32/)

can some one help me on this issue.code snippet would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/marcuswhybrow/3Upgq/

```
var timer = null;

$('button').focus(function() {
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
        // Zoom in here;
    }, 2000);
}).blur(function() {
    if (timer != null)
        clearTimeout(timer);
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/marcuswhybrow/3Upgq/

**IN CONTEXT DEMO:** http://www.jsfiddle.net/jAxg9/34/

Comment: hey thanks for help. i just followed same steps as you said but it is not working for me.here is my demo have look. http://www.jsfiddle.net/jAxg9/33/ if you can tell where am i going wrong it would be very helpful.thanks alot again.

Comment: You were not using jsfiddle correctly. In addition I have fixed the code so it will work: http://www.jsfiddle.net/jAxg9/34/.